# Select only one table in a join query

Tags: magento-2.1, database, collection, sql

I have this working SQL query :

```
SELECT main_table.* FROM prd_brand AS main_table INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity_int ON main_table.brand_id=catalog_product_entity_int.value group by brand_id order by name asc
```

And I'm trying to get it work in Magento, so I did this :

```
        $brandCollection = $brand->getCollection();
        $brandCollection->join('catalog_product_entity_int', 'catalog_product_entity_int.value = main_table.brand_id', '*');
        echo $brandCollection->getSelect();
```

It generates this SQL query:

```
SELECT `main_table`.*, `catalog_product_entity_int`.* FROM `prd_brand` AS `main_table` INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` ON catalog_product_entity_int.value = main_table.brand_id
```

The problem is that I don't like to select the `catalog_product_entity_int` but only the `main_table` (`prd_brand`) table.

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you please try like this it will work

```
$brandCollection = $brand->getCollection();
$brandCollection->join(
    array(
        'cpei' => 'catalog_product_entity_int'),
        'cpei.value = main_table.brand_id',
        array()
    )
```

**Group by use :**

->group ( 'main_table.brand_id' )

**Order by use :**

->order(array('line_items_per_product DESC','product_id'));

Comment: please check and let me know :)

Comment: and it works ! Thank you so much ! what if I want to add 'group by' and 'order by' criterias ?

Comment: Sure i will provide the query

Comment: I updated the code in ans. if any doubts please ask. Thanks